# problems with Reporting Services 2005 to .NET 4 framework on web server

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, reporting, service

We have had custom ASP.NET 3.5 website running for a long time along with a Reporting Services 2005 implementation.  So, that is, on our IIS box (Win 2003 Server, IIS 6), we have our custom .net website and the Reporting Services web services and Report Manager config'd, all on the same box.  The SQL Server 2005 databases (for RS and our own app) are on a separate physical box.

We are now attempting to upgrade to .NET 4.  So I installed the .NET 4 framework on our web server.  We used VS2010 to upgrade our custom ASP.NET 3.5 site to 4 and pushed over the updated web.config to the web server.  Our custom web site is working great under .NET 4, but we are no longer able to run reports (either via our custom integration in our website or even by going to the Reports Manager configured URL).

In either case we get the following error:

"Could not find permission set named 'ASP.Net'"

I've been doing some searches on the error, but so far haven't found anything that's hitting home.  Any thoughts, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to find an answer for this? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Reporting Services virtual directories ("Reports" and "ReportServer" by default) are:

1. Configured as applications, not just virtual directories
2. Using a different app pool than your main site
3. Target ASP.NET 2.0

There are several other issues commonly encountered while hosting RS 2005 under a .NET 4.0 parent site. Just in case you run into these too...

1) The  tag in the parent site's web.config likely has a targetFramework="4.0" attribute. This may choke .NET 2.0 when the configurations settings are inherited by your child RS apps. You can get around this by wrapping the content of the parent site's web.config with a location tag:

```
<configuration>
    <location path='.' inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <!-- all the web.config goo -->
    </location>
</configuration>
```

2) "Path '/[yourApplicationRoot]/eurl.axd/[Value]' was not found." errors. This has to do with extensionless URL support added in ASP.NET 4. There is good documentation on how to address this here: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770153

Comment: he said his site was compiled for 4.0 he cant target 2.0

Comment: It sounds like they upgraded their primary site to 4.0, but the RS app is still running under 2.0. This won't work out of the box without making some (not-so-obvious) configuration changes.